# Mpandroid chart library pie chart Click events

Tags: java, android

I have created pie chart using MP android library my problem is when in click the slice percentage of data need to display center of pie chart and selected pie color should be match the center data which i have selected.please help me to do. here i tried like this but i don't how to set center data color same as slice which i have[attached my screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKgQ6.png)

pieChart.setUsePercentValues(true);

```
    final ArrayList<Entry> yvalues = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    yvalues.add(new Entry(8, 0));
    yvalues.add(new Entry(15, 1));
    yvalues.add(new Entry(12, 2));
    yvalues.add(new Entry(25, 3));

    Log.i("TAG", "helooo" +   yvalues.get(1));

    final PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(yvalues, "Election Results");
    ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();
    xVals.add("January");
    xVals.add("February");
    xVals.add("March");
    xVals.add("April");


    final PieData data = new PieData(xVals, dataSet);
    // In Percentage term
    data.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter());
    // Default value
    data.setValueFormatter(new DefaultValueFormatter(0));
    pieChart.setData(data);
    pieChart.setDescription("This is Pie Chart");
    pieChart.setDrawHoleEnabled(true);
    pieChart.setTransparentCircleRadius(58f);
    pieChart.setHoleRadius(58f);
    dataSet.setColors(colors);
    data.setValueTextSize(13f);
    pieChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);
    pieChart.animateXY(1400, 1400);


    pieChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {
            // display msg when value selected
            if (e == null)
                return;
            dataSet.setValueTextColor(colors[e.getXIndex()]);
            pieChart.setCenterText(yvalues.get(e.getXIndex()) + " \n " + e.getVal() );
            Log.i("PieChart", "selected1" + yvalues.get(0));
           
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected() {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you make custom chart (I means color or percentage or text), you already have list of colors.

when you click value, you can catch event in here

```
@Override
    public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {

        if (e == null)
            return;
        Log.i("VAL SELECTED",
                "Value: " + e.getY() + ", index: " + h.getX()
                        + ", DataSet index: " + h.getDataSetIndex());
    }
```

`e.getY()` is values what you want to show.
and `h.getDataSetIndex()` is positions what you want to get color.

So just make custom TextView in center of your chart for show text and color.
and change this.

p.s] I found show text in center Method.

```
chart.setDrawCenterText(true);
chart.invalidate();
```

So I think you can modified this part. (make custom view for change).

Comment: i tried but i don't know  please refer my  above code and screen shots. thank you

Comment: this is MPchart git. https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart